# Logout in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have this login validation :

```
        public function login_validation() {

            $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email',
            'required|trim|callback_validate_credentials');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required|md5|trim');

            if ($this->form_validation->run()){
                $data= array(
                    'email'=> $this->input->post('email'),
                    'is_logged_in' => true
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                redirect('Pag');
            }else {
                $this->load->view('login');
            }
            }
```

This redirect :

```
        public function members() {
            if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
                redirect('Pag');
            }else{
                redirect('main/restricted');
            }  
            }
```

And this log out:

```
        public function logout() {
            $this->session->unset_userdata('is_logged_in');
            $this->session->sess_destroy();
            redirect('main/login');
        }
```

But when I press Logout from my page I will get redirected to the login tab, but if I write the URL route with /Pag I will get again on the site (without the need to type the credentials), I think that `sess_destroy` don't actually destroy my session.

Comment: Are you checking for the session on `/Pag`?

Comment: How I can do that ?

Comment: Run `members()` function on your `/Pag` page aswell as your login

Answer (score 0):

1. Please make sure your are checking the session at /Page
2. some server have issue(logout issue with www and withought www). You need to use 301 redirect. I managed by this
   In your `.htaccess` file put this code

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]